# How to investigate suspicious Firebase Hosting usage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I was surprised to see a huge uptick on my Google Firebase Hosting Usage tab, where my daily download was suddenly up in the 3-4 GB of hosting downloads! I figured I needed to look into this, but ... how? I can't seem to see a way to figure out who is making all these requests or from where, or what files are being downloaded so much.

I assume that the Google Cloud Console has this data hidden away somewhere, but I couldn't work out how to find it. I looked under https://cloud.google.com/monitoring but I couldn't figure out how to get at the data there either.

I would very much appreciate some help or pointers at how to drill into your Firebase usage beyond the simple 'Usage' tabs the console provides.

Comment: I am not sure whether [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) can help you with this situation. However, I believe you need to follow [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics) in-order to link your Firebase project to Cloud Logging to view, search, and filter your web request logs for each of your Hosting sites.

Comment: Thank you! If you make that not a comment but an answer, I'll mark it down as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: If that helped you, I certainly can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case scenario, it doesn't seems like [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) can do any further assistance.

That's being said, I believe you need to follow [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics) in-order to link your *Firebase project to Cloud Logging* to **view**, **search**, and **filter** your web request logs for each of your **Hosting sites**.